# How to replace a child div on it's existing parent div using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have the following code.

html:

```
<div ng-controller="Test">
         <div ng-click="first()" ng-hide="seconddiv">First
           <div ng-click="second()" ng-show="seconddiv">Second</div> 
         </div>
    </div>
```

js:

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.controller('Test',function($scope){
    $scope.first = function(){
    alert("first clicked");
  }
  $scope.second = function(){
    alert("second clicked");
  }
});
```

On executing the above code:

a). I should see only `First` by default(I can see one now: `First`) - it is fine now

b). then, if I click on `First`, then it should execute it's `first()` method, then `First` should be replaced with `Second(on UI)` - it's not coming

c). then, if I click on `Second`, then it should execute it's `second()` method only, (it should not execute any other methods like `first()` except `second()` method) - it's not coming

I request you to please help me regarding this that how can we do this? Thanks in advance!

Please note that Html `<div>` structure should not change, so it should be same.

Created [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mavdhana/4yfjnby6/) .

Comment: using angular removing jquery

Comment: This isn't going to work;  if you hide the first `div`, you are also hiding it's contents, which happen to be the second `div` as well as the text.  Even if you make the appropriate changes to your code, your HTML structure is wrong.  Just as a side note, if you are concerned with the *exact* positioning of **divs** in an angular app, rather than the positioning of the **content**, you are probably not using angular to it's potential.

Comment: @Claies, Thanks for your reply, then in which way it may work ?

Comment: don't nest the `div` elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go the Angular Way.
You will have just one function, `toggle`. Which will toggle the value of variable `first` from true to false and vice versa.
Depending on value of `first` you will show either div with content as `First` or that with content as `Second`.

You will also refactor your HTML a bit as follows

```
<div ng-controller="Test">
    <div ng-if="first" ng-click="toggle()">First</div>
    <div ng-if="!first"ng-click="toggle()">Second</div> 
</div>
```

And in your JS you will do

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.controller('Test',function($scope){
    $scope.first = true;
    $scope.toggle = function(){
      $scope.first = !$scope.first;
    }
});
```

====
EDIT:

Alternatively, you don't even need the `toggle` function. Just use `ng-click` expression.

```
<div ng-controller="Test">
    <div ng-if="first" ng-click="first=!first">First</div>
    <div ng-if="!first"ng-click="first=!first">Second</div> 
</div>
```

And in JS

```
app.controller('Test',function($scope){
    $scope.first = true;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. your first one is working fine !